# jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.ECMAException: ReferenceError: "Map" is not defined

Tags: javascript, java, nashorn

I'm trying to build an isomorphic app in **React + Spring + Nashorn**, however, I am encountering the following error:

> jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.ECMAException: ReferenceError: "Map" is not defined.

What can be done to correct this?

It seems I've provided too little details. What I'm doing is:
1. I've created 2 js modules: vendor.js (for node_modules) and app.js (my application) (using plugin webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin)
2. Defined nashorn-polyfill.js as follows:

```
var global = this;
var window = this;
var process = {env:{}};

var console = {};
console.debug = print;
console.log = print;
console.warn = print;
console.error = print;
```

3. Created class React which uses Nashorn Javascript Engine to load the 3 js files.

   @Component
   public class React {

   ```
   private static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(React.class);

   @Value(value = "classpath:static/build/nashorn-polyfill.js")
   private Resource nashornPolyfillFile;

   @Value(value = "classpath:static/build/vendor.js")
   private Resource vendorFile;

   @Value(value = "classpath:static/build/app.js")
   private Resource bundleJsFile;

   public String renderEntryPoint() throws ScriptException, IOException {

       NashornScriptEngine nashornScriptEngine = getNashornScriptEngine();

       try {
           Object html = nashornScriptEngine.invokeFunction("renderServer");
           return String.valueOf(html);
       } catch (Exception e) {
           throw new IllegalStateException("Error! Failed to render react component!", e);
       }

   }

   private NashornScriptEngine getNashornScriptEngine() throws ScriptException, IOException {

       NashornScriptEngine nashornScriptEngine = (NashornScriptEngine) new ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByName("nashorn");

       nashornScriptEngine.eval("load('"+nashornPolyfillFile.getURL()+"')");
       nashornScriptEngine.eval("load('"+vendorFile.getURL()+"')");
       nashornScriptEngine.eval("load('"+bundleJsFile.getURL()+"')");

       return nashornScriptEngine;
   }
   ```

   }
4. It seems that line nashornScriptEngine.eval("load('"+vendorFile.getURL()+"')"); gives the mentioned error

2018-01-19 10:17:59.400 ERROR 1332 --- [nio-8095-exec-2] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in con
text with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is javax.script.ScriptException: ReferenceError: "Map" is not defined in file
/build/resources/main/static/build/vendor.js at line number 11241] with root cause

jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.ECMAException: ReferenceError: "Map" is not defined
        at jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.ECMAErrors.error(ECMAErrors.java:57) ~[nashorn.jar:na]
        at jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.ECMAErrors.referenceError(ECMAErrors.java:319) ~[nashorn.jar:na]
        at jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.ECMAErrors.referenceError(ECMAErrors.java:291) ~[nashorn.jar:na]
        at jdk.nashorn.internal.objects.Global.**noSuchProperty**(Global.java:1441) ~[nashorn.jar:na]

Let me know if you need more details.